# Expose module to global Window object with Webpack and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, webpack

I'm using webpack to process and bundle my TypeScript modules, but I need some modules/chunks to be available from the outside. How do I do this?

---

**Additional information**

The code is split up in different directories, one for each page(/component). Every page contains several files, and each file contains a module. It looks something like this:

```
 js/
  ├ page1/
  | ├ entry.ts
  | ├ module1.ts
  | └ module2.ts
  ├ page2/
  | ├ entry.ts
  | ├ module3.ts
  | └ module4.ts
```

The TypeScript modules are defined like

```
import {Module2} from "./module2";
export module Module1 {

    export function someFunc():int {
        return Module2.someVal;
    }

}
```

And I'm using gulp-webpack to compile and bundle the modules for each page:

```
gulp.task('javascript', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/js/**/entry.ts')
        .pipe(named(function (file) {
            // Sets file.named to the containing directory name (used by webpack)
            return path.dirname(file.path).substr(path.dirname(file.path).replace(/\\/g, '/').lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        }))
        .pipe(webpack({
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
                ]
            },
            plugins: [
                new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                    name: "bundle",
                    minChunks: 3
                })
            ],
            output: {
                filename: '[name].js'
            },
            devtool: 'source-map'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/js'))
});
```

Now I need the `Module1.someFunc()` to be accessible from the global scope, so it can be used by other (external) components. I've looked at the [expose loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader), but I don't see how that can work in this situation.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with expose loader anyway. In an entry.ts I used:

```
import x = require("expose-loader?M1!./module1");
```

Which made the function available through `M1.Module1.someFunc()` from the outside. Both my IDE and gulp-webpack threw an error, but in the end it still worked somehow. Good enough for me!

Comment: Can you get away without the `import x = ` part, and just have the require?

Comment: This also seems to function as just `import "expose-loader?M1!./module1"`